# Excel array formula using INDEX, MATCH, and ROW functions only sometimes calculates automatically

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Following this tutorial: https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2654-excel-dynamic-list-remove-blanks.html?page_comment=2

I have the formula:

```
{=IFERROR(INDEX($H$7:$H$5000,MATCH(ROW()-ROW($L$6),$F$7:$F$5000,0)),"")}
```

that I've entered in cells K7:K5000

Sometimes when I change the precedent cells, the formula will recalculate, but other times, it won't. What is going on and how can I fix it?

Note: I have my formulas set to automatic calculations and I'm using Microsoft Office 365 ProPlus on Windows 10.

Comment: BTW that is not an array formula.

Comment: Why use `Row($L$6)`?? It will always return 6, so why not just write that? Also, show a concrete example of the formula not recalculating. Can that be reproduced?

Comment: @ScottCraner you are correct. After reading various threads trying to come up with a solution, it seemed as though people were using array formulas to force volatility, but on a second look, I don't think that's the case. The problem persists whether or not the formula is entered as an array formula or not.

Comment: @teylyn I was following the tutorial in the included link which uses that syntax; it helps if I need to add rows above the formula. What's the best way to show a formula not recalculating? It would be difficult to fit in 500+ rows into a readable screenshot.

Comment: @user7758051,, nothing wrong with the Formula and it works as an Array Formula also,,, and in `ROW($L$6)` the Row number matters which must be `6` whether is even `$A$6`,, I think due to huge Cell Range sometimes principally due to SPEED of the Microprocessor,,  Formula fails to reflect with New Data !!